# Why is file AWS_restXML.js included in minified bundle?

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I am creating a bundle of a AWS Lambda function that uses `@aws-sdk/client-s3`. The largest file in the bundle according to https://esbuild.github.io/analyze/ is `AWS_restXML.js` coming in at **143 kb**. Bundle is created using esbuild with tree shaking enabled. I am using the `S3Client` and commands as recommended to minimise bundle sizes.

Is that as expected? If not, is there a way to reduce bundle size further?